# Revit addin, Reset all values of forms when start

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I created an add in on Revit using a form. When i start the add in for the first time (add-in tab in revit and external tool and "my program"), it correctly execute the Initialization of the form but, when i close it and re-open it (always add-in tab and external tool and "my program") it doesn't execute the program i put behind IniatilizeComponent().

```
namespace Import_Selected_DET
{
    public partial class Interface_LIB : Form
    {
        #region Variables
        public static string chemFAB = "";
        static string chemGAM = "";
        static string chemREP = "";//Correspond au chemin de fichier le plus avancé
        static string thisOne = "";//Repertoire dans lequel se trouve le fichier a prendre
        static string chemLIB = @"C:\ProgramData\Letitbim";
        static string chemProg = chemLIB + @"\Import_Selected_DET";
        static string chemRes = chemProg + @"\Ressources.txt";
        static int compteErreur = 0;
        static string utilisateur = Environment.UserName;

        #endregion
        public Interface_LIB()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //This part doesn't execute the second time... Why ?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you closing the window or just hidding it? Make sure that you destroy the window object when you close it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was find on Autodesk Forum. There is a link :

https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/c-addin-form-reset-the-form-when-show/m-p/9459022/highlight/false#M46368

Thank you **Adrian Efford** and **Jeremy Tammik** for your comment and Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Adrian says above, if you destroy the window all its data will disappear.

When you recreate it, you have to add new data.

This question is being discussed in more depth as I write in the Revit API discussion forum thread on [C# Addin form, Reset the form when show](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/c-addin-form-reset-the-form-when-show/m-p/9447060) (DAS ticket 16479364).